# Another space between divs issue, other answers not working

Tags: html, spaces

Got a space between just one div in a web page. Recreated it as jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/durN4/

The problem is between the "Switzerland Inn on the Blue Ridge Parkway" banner and the main text below it. There is a space at the top and the bottom of the div tag. Here is the css code as found on the jsfiddle page...

```
#main_holder {
width: 75%;
min-width: 750px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border: 5px solid #E2BE6A;
position: relative;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 5px rgba(2, 1, 14, 0.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 5px rgba(2, 1, 14, 0.6);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 5px rgba(2, 1, 14, 0.6);
height: auto;
}
#headline {
height: 155px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #E2BE6A;
width: 100%;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #327EEF 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #327EEF 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #327EEF 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #327EEF));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #327EEF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF 0%, #327EEF 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFFFF",endColorstr="#327EEF",GradientType=1);
}
#rotator_holder {
height: 321px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom-width: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #E2BE6A;
position: relative;
}
#navbar {
height:35px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom-width: 5px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #E2BE6A;
position: relative;
background-color: #FFF1CE;

}
#titlebar {
font-family: 'Habibi', serif;
font-size: 24px;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #327EEF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #327EEF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #327EEF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #327EEF), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #327EEF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #327EEF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#327EEF",endColorstr="#FFFFFF",GradientType=0);
color: #000;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#main_content {
font-size: 18px;
background-color: #FFF1CE;
width: 100%;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px 6px #c4c6cf;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px 6px #c4c6cf;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px 6px #c4c6cf;
}
#padding {
width: 94%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using `padding-left` instead of `&nbsp;` to indent text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by the margins on `h1` and the last `p` inside `main_content`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38VKa/)

```
#main_content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#main_content h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is called [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). It's the margin of the `h1` element in the main text that pushes its container down.

When an element doesn't have a padding or border, and a child element has a margin, that margin doesn't apply between the child element and the parent boundaries, but outside the parent element.

So, there are several ways that you could fix it, depending on what result you want:

- Remove the top margin of the `h1` element
- Add a padding to the top of the container
- add a border to the top of the container